# Problema de array em C, onde está o erro?

Tags: c, array, algoritmo, matriz

Tenho o seguinte problema para resolver:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cheguei nessa solução:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    double numeros[99];
    double resultante[49];

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&numeros[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<=49;i++)
    {
        resultante[i] = numeros[i]*numeros[100-i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<=49;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",resultante[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de saber por que esse código não está funcionando, os retornos são estranhos, parecem-se com endereços, mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar se são 100 elementos você deve declarar `double numeros[100], resultante[50];` e não 99 e 49 como declarou. Note que para 100 elementos o índice do array irá variar de 0 até 99.

Faltou calcular a soma como pedido no problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double numeros[100], resultante[50], soma=0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&numeros[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=49;i++) {
        resultante[i] = numeros[i]*numeros[99-i];
        soma += resultante[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<=49;i++) {
        printf("\t%d",resultante[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSoma: %d\n", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário